# Full Calendar Jquery with Google calendar API v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-plugins, calendar

I am using the Jquery Full calendar plugin with Google Calendar. Google calendar returns me a Json response of Events List but Events are not displayed in my Calendar but display the success alert. i donot know why it misses my Events.

```
HRBC.controllers.Calendar = function () {
    this.load = function (calendarId, tempURL, tempToken) {
        $(calendarId).fullCalendar({

            eventSources: [{
                url: tempURL,
                type: 'GET',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + tempToken); },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('Very Good');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert('error');

                }
            }],

            cache: true,
            eventClick: function (event) {
                // opens events in a popup window
                window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
                return false;
            },

            loading: function (bool) {
                if (bool) {
                    $('#loading').show();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
                    }, 1);

                } else {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged google-maps-api-3?

Comment: I am getting the good Json but now i am trying to convert into an array but still no results.